# Handling Errors in Nodejs Application when Redis fails

Tags: express, redis, web-applications, microservices

I have written a module named Cache in my express application,Which uses Redis for caching,I instantiaited Redis during app initialisation,I want to handle errors across the application,incase of Redis fails,such that if I use Redis module in other modules,it should not throw errors and crash entire application.Are there any ways to handle this?

My code looks like this,

```
In App.ts,
//Initiate Express
//Initiate Database
Cache.init();

In Cache.ts ,
class Cache {
private cache;
public async init() {
        try {
            const url = 'redis://localhost:6379';
            this.client = redis.createClient(url);

            this.client.on('error', (err) => {
                console.error('Redis Error:', err.message);
            });
            this.client.on('connect', () => {
                console.log('Redis Connected!');
            });
            this.client.on('end', () => {
                console.log('No Redis instance found, quitting');
            });
            this.client.on('ready', () => {
                console.log('Redis connected and listening');
            });
            await this.client.connect();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error during Redis initialization:', err.message);
            this.client.quit();
        } 
         public getClient(){
           return this.client;
           }

}
In Books.ts,
class Books {
const getBooks = () => {
const client = Rcache.getRedisClient()
const books = /* DB query */
client.set('books',books)
}
}
```

so,In other modules,If I use this cache in other modules for storing and retrieving through cache,if I didnt have Redis running ,it throws error in Cache module,if I call getBooks method,it throws error and crashes the app,I wanted my application to be run even though Redis fails,Is there any way to do this?